# Can I use Twilio for making outbound calls from UK

Tags: outbound

I am looking at making outbound telesales calls to UK.

Can I use Twilio for this

Do I need to install anything on my server or is this hosted solution.

Do I need a separate dialler

Is there a CRM built in.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

Yes, you can make outbound phone calls from our UK phone numbers to other UK phone numbers or from our UK phone numbers to other international numbers.

Twilio is a telephony platform, its not an out of the box solution so while you generally don't need to install anything Twilio specific on your server, its likely that you would need to actually program some kind of application that uses the Twilio platform.  That application would need to be hosted on a server.

Twilio itself does not have a built in CRM, however we have a number of customers (like [ringDNA](http://www.ringdna.com/)) who have created integration's with popular CRM's like SalesForce and Microsoft Dynamics.  If you are looking for an out of the box solution I'd start by checking out our [Partner Showcase](https://www.twilio.com/showcase), specific the [Sales Communication](https://www.twilio.com/showcase/breakout/sales-communication) section.

Hope that helps.